# Qt c++ VS code : how to use relative file path?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, resources

I'm using Qt6 Framework in VS code on Mac.
I have a Window.h and Window.cpp files to create window using QOpenGLWindow and QOpenGLFunctions.

> Window.h

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QOpenGLWindow>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QOpenGLVertexArrayObject>

class QOpenGLShaderProgram;

class Window: public QOpenGLWindow, protected QOpenGLFunctions{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ~Window();

    // opengl events
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
    void paintGL();
    void teardownGL();

private:
    // opengl state information
    QOpenGLBuffer m_vertex;
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject m_object;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram *m_program;

    // private helper
    void printContextInformation();
};

#endif /* WINDOW_H */
```

> Window.cpp

```
#include "hdr/Window.h"
#include "hdr/Vertex.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>

// create a colored triangle
static const Vertex sg_vertexes[] = {
    Vertex( QVector3D( 0.00f,  0.75f, 1.0f), QVector3D(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ),
    Vertex( QVector3D( 0.75f, -0.75f, 1.0f), QVector3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) ),
    Vertex( QVector3D(-0.75f, -0.75f, 1.0f), QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) )
};

Window::~Window(){
    makeCurrent();
    teardownGL();
}

// ----- opengl events -----
void Window::initializeGL(){
    // initialize opengl backend
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    printContextInformation();

    ...

    // application-specific initialization
    {
        // create shader dDo not release until vao is created)
        m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        m_program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, "shaders/vertexShader.vert");
        m_program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "shaders/fragmentShader.frag");
        m_program->link();
        m_program->bind();

        ...
    }
}

void Window::resizeGL(int width, int height){
    ...
}

void Window::paintGL(){
    ...
}    

void Window::teardownGL(){
    ...
}

// ----- private helper -----
void Window::printContextInformation(){
    ...
}
```

So, in my window.cpp I'm adding shader from source file using relative path "shaders/vertexShader.vert" / "shaders/fragmentShader.frag" but that doesn't work.
Actually my only way to use my shader files is to put the entire file path ("/Users/[name]/c++/WuW/res/shaders/vertexShader.vert" / "/Users/[name]/c++/WuW/res/shaders/fragmentShader.frag").

This is how my project folder is organized:

[image: Project folder (project name is "WuW")]

> CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)
project(wuw VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

if(NOT DEFINED INSTALL_EXAMPLESDIR)
    set(INSTALL_EXAMPLESDIR "examples")
endif()

set(INSTALL_EXAMPLEDIR "${INSTALL_EXAMPLESDIR}/WuW/Build")

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Gui)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS OpenGL)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS OpenGLWidgets)

add_executable(wuw
    src/main.cpp
    src/Window.cpp hdr/Window.h
    hdr/Vertex.h
)

set_target_properties(wuw PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
)

target_include_directories(wuw PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(wuw PUBLIC
    Qt::Core
    Qt::Widgets
    Qt::Gui
    Qt::OpenGL
    Qt::OpenGLWidgets
)

install(TARGETS wuw
    RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_EXAMPLEDIR}"
    BUNDLE DESTINATION "${INSTALL_EXAMPLEDIR}"
    LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_EXAMPLEDIR}"
)
```

Comment: Just run your application with source directory being as **working directory**. If you run your application via VSCode, then configure VSCode accordingly.

Comment: Or put the shaders into a Qt resource file or relative to your executable and use QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()

Answer (score 1):

**[Resolved]**

I created a res.qrc file in my res folder with this code:

> res.qrc

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version = "1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>shaders/fragmentShader.frag</file>
    <file>shaders/vertexShader.vert</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

and added this file to executable:

> CMakeFiles.txt

```
add_executable(wuw
    res/res.qrc (that line)
    src/main.cpp
    src/Window.cpp hdr/Window.h
    hdr/Vertex.h
)
```

Now I can use the relative path of the shader files:

> Window.cpp

```
...
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(res);

// ----- opengl events -----
void Window::initializeGL(){
    // initialize opengl backend
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    printContextInformation();

    // set global information
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(res);

    // application-specific initialization
    {
        // create shader dDo not release until vao is created)
        m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        m_program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/shaders/vertexShader.vert");
        m_program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/shaders/fragmentShader.frag");
        m_program->link();
        m_program->bind();
    
        ...
    }
}

...
```

Thanks @chehrlic !